# How can I upgrade to Discord.js V13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im using Discord.js V13 and when i try to run the bot i get this error everytime.

Main File:

```js
const { Discord, Intents } = require('discord.js'); 

const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  partials: ["CHANNEL","MESSAGE","REACTION"],
  intents: [Intents.ALL] 
});
```

The error:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Client')
```

The solution here is that i can`t deconstruct the library from itself, and my mistake is that i needed to put only the intents that my bot needs.

My solution:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 

const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  partials: ["CHANNEL","MESSAGE","REACTION"],
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,                // <--line 5 here
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES
  ]               
});
```

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/general/welcome)? It has an example of getting the client right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deconstruct the library from itself.

Either deconstruct the client:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client(...);
// ...
```

Or utilitize the library entirely:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client(...);
// ...
```